# Obtener dato en específico de una respuesta obtenida por una conexión

Tags: php, curl

hice una conexión con Curl y obtuve unos datos, ahora lo que estoy intentando hacer es sacar únicamente el dato access_token pero no me está quedando.
¿Como es que tendría que hacerlo?

> Conexión

```
      $ch = curl_init();
      $url = "URL";
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                //0 for a get request
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      echo ($response);
      curl_close ($ch);
```

> Respuesta

```
{"access_token":"1000.54bcccd8b69c4affc6fe47c971a281d1.2111f2edc93c83376db6540082b2e434","api_domain":"https://www.zohoapis.com","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

Bonito día.

Answer (score 0):

> Decodifiqué primero el JSON que obtuve

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($response);
```

> Finalmente saque el dato que necesitaba.

```
echo ($obj->{'access_token'});
curl_close ($ch);
```